# Class inside a class

Tags: c++

I'm writing a 3d asset importing library. (it uses [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/), btw). There's a big scene that contains nodes that contain meshes, and each mesh contains a material. So I created the next classes: Scene, Mesh, Material.

Only the Scene class should be instantiated and used by the coder, so the most reasonable thing to do (imo) would be to declare Mesh as a private inside Scene (and also Material as private inside Mesh).

This should be fine as only Scene is and should be using Mesh, but the only problem is that it just looks awful and it's not convenient for me to code this way. (functions nesting in classes nesting in classes etc...)

My question is if there are other coding approaches to accomplish my goals.

Comment: I am not generally a fan of `friend`s, but you could make the `Mesh` constructor private and make `Scene` a `friend` so that it is allowed to instantiate `Mesh`.

Comment: If only a `Scene` can be instantiated, how do you propose creating a `Mesh` to add to the `Scene`, or a `Material` to add to a `Mesh`, without instantiating either a `Mesh` or a `Material` or both? It would probably be better for a `Scene` to have some container-like methods, and allow both `Mesh` and `Material` to be instantiated as needed and added to the `Scene` as appropriate...

Comment: @twalberg Scene gets fed with an import file. Its responsibility is to get all the 3d stuff into memory and it uses Mesh and Material to do so. The user shouldn't care about Mesh and Material.

Answer (score 5):

You can look into the [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). Basically, expose only what a client should and can use in the public interface, and keep everything else abstracted away:

```
// scene_interface.h
class SceneImpl; //only forward-declare
class Scene
{
    // client-visible methods, and that's all
    // no implementation details
private:
    SceneImpl* pImpl; // <- look, the name
};


// scene_impl.h & scene_impl.cpp
// hidden from the client
class Mesh
{
   //...
};
class SceneImpl
{
   Mesh* pMesh;
   //etc.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the private classes to incomplete declarations in the header (`.h`) file, and then define them fully in the implementation (`.cpp`) file.

Header `Scene.h`:

```
class Scene
{
    // ...
private:
    class Node;
    class Mesh;

    Node *node;
    Mesh *mesh;
};
```

Implementation `Scene.cpp`:

```
class Scene::Node
{
    // ...
};

class Scene::Mesh
{
    // ...
};

// definitions of member functions ...
```

Comment: The user will still be able to instantiate new Nodes and Meshes. This doesn't help me

Comment: @Pilpel: No the user will not be able to instantiate `Node`s and `Mesh`es. He will only be able to declare pointers to them. If you don't even want that, you can declare the classes inside the `private` section of `Scene` and then prefix the definitions with `Scene::` in the implementation file.

Comment: @Pilpel: I've modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Why doesn't this: http://pastebin.com/vSa5t22v gets compiled? The errors I get are noted below the code

Comment: @Pilpel: Because the constructor for `InBase` is defined in the implementation file, and is unavailable in the header where you defined the `Base` constructor. You need to define the `Base` constructor also in the implementation file, not in the header.